# Cannot deploy firebase security through CLI for asia_southeast1 database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cli

I migrated the database from us-central1 to asia_southeast1.  I'd like to deploy the security rule to the new database but it doesn't work.  The followings are the steps I took and the result:

(The new db called abc-asia-db, the whole database URL is https://abc-asia-db.asia-southeast1.firebasedatabase.app/)

`firebase target:apply database main abc-asia-db`

In firebase.json Replace database script with the followings

```
"database": 
    [{"target": "main","rules": "database.rules.json"},
    {"target": "other","rules": "other.rules.json"}]
```

`firebase deploy --only database`

Then, it shows the following error message:

`Error: Failed to get instance details for instance: abc-asia-db. See firebase-debug.log for more details.`

If I created the new database in us-central1, it works well.  The security rule can be deployed successfully.  However, if I create the new database in asia_southeast1, it doens't work.

I use Mac OS and can't find the debug.log in my computer.  There are the only files in the folder.

```
drwxr-xr-x  19 xxx  staff   608 Aug 27 13:16 ..
drwxr-xr-x  12 xxx  staff   384 Oct  5 14:39 functions
-rw-r--r--@  1 xxx  staff   644 Oct  5 15:41 database.rules.json
-rw-r--r--@  1 xxx  staff   643 Oct  5 16:28 other.rules.json
-rw-r--r--   1 xxx  staff   382 Oct  5 16:47 .firebaserc
-rw-r--r--   1 xxx  staff   467 Oct  6 11:52 firebase.json
drwxr-xr-x   9 xxx  staff   288 Oct  6 12:44 .
```

Comment: Your `firebase.json` file definition for databases seems incorrect. Have a look here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/sharding#edit_and_deploy_for_each_instance.

Comment: Could you post the content of debug.log?

Comment: I updated the firebase.json as the example but it has the same result.

Comment: I use macos, would you mind to tell us where can I get the debug.log?

Comment: In the same folder as where you executed the command.

Comment: There is no debug.log in the folder

Answer (score 0):

Your `firebase.json` is probably malformed. In the [example](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/sharding#edit_and_deploy_for_each_instance) they have only one rule file per database. In your example, I see a duplicate entry for the main database. Try using this `firebase.json` content as an example:

```
{
  "database": [
    {"target": "main", "rules": "database.rules.json"}
  ]
}
```

Comment: I updated the firebase.json as the example but it has the same result.